# Python - Exclude rows by checking strings in other columns

Tags: python, dataframe, function

Slightly long question so please bear with me.

I am trying to remove unnecessary text from the email body and keep only the body (text that follows the greetings and before the signature) from the first email.

Below is a sample email.

Email:

```
email = """Hi John,

I am emailing regarding REQ-12345 and REQ-66442.

Many Thanks,

Jane
Analyst | XYZ LLC.
Phone: +00 123 456 7890
Email: Jane.Doe@xyzmail.com
"""
```

I used the `splitlines` and `startswith` method to check each line for the keywords using which I want to decide weather to include or exclude a line.

Code:

```
flag = []
greet = []
for i in range(len(email.splitlines())):
   
    if email.splitlines()[i].lower().startswith('many thanks'):
        flag.append(False)
    else:
        flag.append(True)
        
    if email.splitlines()[i].lower().startswith('hi') or email.splitlines()[i].lower().startswith('hello'):
        greet.append(False)
    else:
        greet.append(True)

df = pd.DataFrame({'line': email.splitlines(), 'signature_flag': flag, 'greet': greet})
df
```

Gives below dataframe:

[image]

I created a function called `countX` to check the number of times a value appears in a list.

```
def countX(lst, x): 
    count = 0
    for ele in lst: 
        if (ele == x): 
            count = count + 1
    return count
```

Using the `countX` function, I am trying to create a column where if `signature_flag` or `greet` columns are `False`, it should be marked as `False` and if `False` has appeared in the `final_flag` twice, then anything after the second `False` would be `False`. I can then drop all the `False` rows and whatever remains would be my required text.

```
final_flag = []
for i in range(len(df)):
    flag = (df['signature_flag'][i] == True & df['greet'][i] == True)
    if countX(final_flag[0:i], False) <= 2:
        final_flag.append(flag)
    else:
        final_flag.append(False)
df['final_flag'] = final_flag
df
```

However, this is not working as expected.

How do I get this working?

Thanks.

Comment: what is your expected output from the given dataframe?

Answer (score 0):

As you are using final_flag after string slicing, so you should use i+1 to include upto i elements in the list.

```
if countX(final_flag[0:i + 1], False) <= 2:
    final_flag.append(flag)
```

Comment: Hi @Shubham Chaudhary, Just tried this. But I am not getting the desired results.

Comment: Hi, Is the length of df accurate?

Comment: It is. Its based on the text above. I resolved this issue. Basically created a new column where I marked anything that had a false in either of the two columns as False and anything after the second False as False. Filtered out the True values.